# Transfer effect not working (and I have a style for ui-effects-transfer!)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I can't get the jQuery UI Transfer effect to work. Similar question on StackOverflow were solved by specifying a .ui-effects-transfer style, but I have that. I'm trying to create a transfer effect from #popup to #target. Here's my code. Thanks in advance.

```
    <html>
        <head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

        .ui-effects-transfer { border: 2px dotted black; }

        #popup {        
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            top: 20px;
            left: 20px;
            background-color: red;
        }

        #target {
            position: absolute;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            top: 500px;
            left: 500px;
            background-color: blue;
        }       
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {      

            var $popup = $('#popup');       
            $popup.click(function() {
                $popup.effect('transfer', {to: $('#target')}, 2000);                        
            });     
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>    
        <div id="popup">        
        </div> 

        <div id="target">       
        </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Looks like it works well here...
Are you using IE, Chrome or FF?

[http://jsfiddle.net/9K8TD/](http://jsfiddle.net/9K8TD/)

Comment: I've tried it in Firefox 6.0 and IE 9. This is truly baffling.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. I also had to link to the jquery.effects.transfer script. Evidently each effect has its own js file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class `ui-effects-transfer` to the options and simply give the target css identifier for `to:` without giving as jquery identifier i.e. `to: "#target"`

finally your code should look like:

`$popup.effect('transfer',to: '#target',className:'ui-effects-transfer' 2000);`

[see the code source here](http://jqueryui.com/effect/) by selecting effect as "transfer".